# Query mongo with an id array in where clause ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

Let's say I have a table Users in the database. The user table has article_id. I also have an array let's say article_ids. Now I want to take all the users in the database that have article_id in that array of ids. 
I am trying to with the following query:

`User.where(article_id: article_ids)`.

However this query gives me the following error: `TypeError: Cannot visit Moped::BSON::ObjectId`

Answer (score 2):

```
User.where(article_id: {'$in': article_ids})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
User.where(article_id: article_ids.map { |id| BSON::ObjectId(id) })
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10585521)

Comment: If you read question carefully you will notice that there no question at all. I predicted a question and answer it.

Comment: so, you actually agree that your _prediction_ is not an answer to the post.